# Constructing useful lemmas

Tags: isabelle

In the tutorial *Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL* there's a step-by-step explanation of the proof of reversing a list twice yields the original list (2.2.4 The Proof Process).

```
theorem rev_rev [simp]: "rev(rev xs) = xs"
apply(induction xs)
apply(auto)
```

Following the auto step one subgoal remains:

```
1. V x1 xs.
     rev (rev xs) = xs =⇒
     rev (app (rev xs) (Cons x1 Nil)) = Cons x1 xs
```

The author then says "In order to simplify this subgoal further, a lemma suggests itself.", and presents the rev_app lemma below:

```
lemma rev_app [simp]: "rev(app xs ys) = app (rev ys) (rev xs)"
```

Is it just intuition and practice, just like in pen and paper proofs, that enables one to see how subgoal 1. could be simplified and come up with a lemma like rev_app? I simply can't recognize how this lemma suggests itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is indeed tricky for people unfamiliar with formal proof developments. Over time, one will learn many heuristic approaches to come up with potential lemmas.

In this case (purely equational reasoning) the heuristic usually works by looking at the involved constants of the subgoals.

The main lemma, for example, describes a `rev`/`rev` property. The subgoal however needs something about `rev`/`app`. This is what tells you that you need a lemma about these two.

The remainder can, unfortunately, be only be described as "human ingenuity": to see that `rev(app xs ys) = app (rev ys) (rev xs)` is a reasonable property on `rev`/`app`.

There is various research on detecting such properties automatically, for example [IsaHipster](https://github.com/moajohansson/IsaHipster).

Comment: Paraphrasing Tobias Nipkow, using a proof assistant does not remove intuition from mathematical reasoning. Intuition is important and while it is possible to use a proof assistant without it, I doubt one will get very far. The role of formal reasoning (with or without a computer) is not to eliminate intuition from mathematics, but to eliminate the need of having to *trust* one's intuition. You use intuition to come up with your proof, then you formalise it, and then you can be reasonably certain that it really is true.

Comment: Another small hint for equational reasoning: When you have a goal involving two such functions, you will typically need auxiliary facts relating them, and in the equational case, you will probably need some lemmas about how they commute. It is a fairly common situation to have a subterm like `f (g x)` or `f (g x) (g y)` for some fixed functions `f` and `g`. The usual thing that you want the simplifier to do is to push in the `f`, or to somehow ‘cancel’ the `f` and the `g`.